# Set group id is equal to 2 for wholesale customer registration in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer, registration

Hello everyone I want to set **group_id = 2** for wholesale customer registration.
I have to override the registration form in **view/registration.phtml**
and also written

```
<input type="hidden" name="group_id" id="group_id" value="2" />
```

I have also created the observer

> Magneto\WholesaleCustomer\Observer\Customer\RegisterSuccess.php

```
<?php 


 namespace Magneto\WholesaleCustomer\Observer\Customer;

 use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;




 class RegisterSuccess implements 
\Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface {

 /**
 * @var CustomerRepositoryInterface
 */
 //added by me
private $customerRepository;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
     CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
    )
{
    $this->_request = $request;
    $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
}
//ends here
public function execute(
    \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
){      

    $id = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer()->getId();
    $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($id);

     $group_id = $this->_request->getParam('group_id');

    $customer->setGroupId($group_id);

    $this->customerRepository->save($customer);

}
}
```

But the group id is coming 1 in the database I want to set it as 2 in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first create event.xml file for your observer `Vendor\Module\etc\frontend\events.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_register_success">
        <observer name="persistent" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\ChangeCustomerGroupId" />
    </event>
</config>
```

and create observer after that `Vendor\Module\Observer\ChangeCustomerGroupId.php`

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class ChangeCustomerGroupId implements ObserverInterface
{

    protected $_customerRepositoryInterface;
    protected $_request;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface,
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
    ) {
        $this->_customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
        $this->_request = $request;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
        if ($customer->getGroupId() == 1) {
            $postData = $this->_request->getPost();
            $customer->setGroupId($postData["group_id"]);
            $this->_customerRepositoryInterface->save($customer);;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: nothing change group id is passing 1

Comment: can you share your event.xml code?

Comment: i does not created event.xml

Comment: so how would your observer work?

Comment: can you share me the event.xml code?

Comment: sure, editing my answer

Comment: ok waiting for your reply

Comment: Check my answer now. Hope it will work :)

Comment: i want ask one thing where to write this line in registration.phtml <input type="hidden" name="group_id" id="group_id" value="2" />

Comment: inside form in the file `vendor\magento\module-customer-custom-attributes\view\frontend\templates\customer\form\register.phtml` and obviously you need to override this file in your theme

Comment: i am doing thorugh model i have override in view/registration.phtml

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90855/discussion-between-shoaib-munir-and-ashish-ramchandani).

Comment: I don't know what's wrong in this answer, someone given downvote, +1 for answer and I hope this satisfy the requirement. @ShoaibMunir

Comment: I don't know why someone gave -1, I am just trying to help and giving whatever I have in my knowledge